# Node throwing Unexpected strict mode reserved word "yield"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

Been struggling with this for a while and honestly its eating me alive, this is a typescript code being mapped to javascript code. Source is

```
const connection: Connection = await createConnection();
```

From [TypeORM](http://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/creating-a-new-connection-from-the-configuration-file) which converts to

```
const connection = yield typeorm_1.createConnection();
```

Which this then throws

```
/path/to/api/build/routes/admin.js:22
        let admins = yield con.manager.find(Admin_1.Admin);
                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lulliezy/Documents/Projects/blog/api/build/app.js:10:13)
```

I have searched everywhere but i havent found a solution yet, and its driving me nuts, any solution or fixes or work arounds to this? I will highly appreciate, thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

Okay I finally found what I was doing wrong. I was missing an `async` keyword before the function I called that line in, I was to make it `async` so it was supposed to go somehow like this

```
/*****/
async function() {
    const connection: Connection = await createConnection();
}
/****/
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly the issue; a missing `async` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

As David rightly said, using generators in asynchronous operation for a synchronous process, you will have you restructure your code to:

```
const co = require('co');

co(function*() {
    "use strict";

   /path/to/api/build/routes/admin.js:22
     let admins = yield con.manager.find(Admin_1.Admin);
```

**NOTE:** When using `use strict` mode, don't use `yield` outside the `co(function*() {`. As it will end up throwing that error again.

And you might want to read more on how [function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) are used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a generator to overcome this issue. [**Co**](https://github.com/tj/co) is one of such popular generator which will help you to write/execute non-blocking code.

Install it using the below command

```
npm install co
```

And then wrap your code inside co which will prevent errors being thrown based on keywords. Like this,

```
var co = require('co');

co(function*() {
    "use strict";
     .................
     ........................
     let admins = yield con.manager.find(Admin_1.Admin);
     .................
     ........................
    return something;
}).then(function (returnVal) {
    console.log (returnVal);
}, function (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
});
```

Hope this helps!